# How to convert a StringVar to an Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, type-conversion

I'm writing a basic number guessing game, and I'm trying to put the program into a window. Everything works fine except when I try to access the variable created in my `entry_box` and then compare it to an `int`.

Right now, the variable coming out of the `entry_box` is a `StringVar`. How do I convert this to an integer so I can compare the variables?

```
# Creates the entry box and variable that will be used in it
# answer = StringVar()
entry_box = Entry(window, textvariable = answer, width = 25, bg = 'white') .place(x = 350, y = 0)

num1 = answer.get()
```

So right now answer is a StringVar, and im trying to convert it to an Integer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `num1 = int(answer.get())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use int():

```
num1 = int(answer.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is the same way you convert *any* string to an integer in Python:

```
num1 = answer.get() # now we have a str
num2 = int(num1) # now we have an int
```

Of course if the user typed something like `spam` in the Entry—or nothing at all—that second line is going to raise a `ValueError`. You have to decide how you want to handle that.

(For a fancier project, you might want to consider using an `IntVar` instead of a `StringVar` and/or using manual Tkinter validation, but for a simple exercise, you probably don't need that.)